# Qual a maneira segura se trabalhar com TRicheEdit Banco de Dados?

Tags: delphi, postgresql, richtextbox

Estou fazendo essa pergunta porque a dias estou tendo uma dor de cabe enorme com essa tranqueira de RichEdit, hora ele salva correto hora ele salva um monte de ???????????? na base... sei que pode ser erro na conversão de caracteres mas o detalhe é que o problema é intermitente.

Se for a primeira vez que gravo ele grava corretamente

Se for edição ele grava um monte de caracteres estranhos, tipo chines.

Se eu limpar a base e inserir o texto novamente e grava corretamente.

As vezes na edição ele grava corretamente.

Eu gostaria de trocar tudo por HTML mas é inviável, são anos de gravação tudo em RichEdit, pois preciso do texto formatado.

A forma que estou fazendo segue abaixo:

```
  ...
  fdm.RichStream := TStringStream.Create(fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.AsAnsiString);
  //fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.SaveToStream(fdm.RichStream);

  f_richedit := Tf_richedit.Create(nil);
  fdm.RichStream.Position := 0;
  f_richedit.RichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(fdm.RichStream);
  TFuncoes.pJustRichEdit(f_richedit.RichEdit, False);
  f_richedit.ShowModal;

  if (fdm.Salvar) then
  begin
    fdm.zqrAux_Aet_Texto.Edit;
    fdm.RichStream.Position := 0;
    fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.LoadFromStream(fdm.RichStream);//AsString := fdm.RichStream.DataString;
    fdm.zqrAux_Aet_Texto.Post;
    fdm.zConecta.Commit;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(fdm.RichStream); // .Free;
  fdm.zqrAux_Aet_Texto.Close;
  f_richedit := nil;
```

Observe em alguns "comentados" que ja tentei salvar de outras formas, mas o problema continua

A base de dados é postgresql, mas acho que nem vem ao caso, porque ele grava texto la e esta com UTF8 e tudo como pede o figurino

Alguem sabem uma maneira segura de trabalhar com esse RichEdit?

Digo segura porque correta ja nem sei mais, rs

Comment: `fdm.Salvar` é um método ou apenas uma variável booleana?
E pelo que vi você joga os dados em um richedit, formata os dados só que no fim grava o que ta no `fdm.RichStream` e não o que está formatado no `f_richedit.RichEdit`

Comment: Acredito que já tenha resolvido seu problema, mas passei pelo mesmo problema.
Banco Firebird, tinha um campo Blob subtype 1 segment size 5.
Esse tipo de campo serve textos pequenos, num entorno de 10MB de caracteres.
Solução: Mudar para blob subtype 0 segment size 80; Opções e definições do campo Blob
MEMO as blob subtype 1 segment size 5;
FIGURA as blob subtype 0 segment size 50;
TEXTO as blob subtype 0 segment size 80; usamos o MEMO para textos pequenos, num entorno de 10MB de caracteres.
usamos FIGURA para armazenar imgens, somente imagens.
usamos TEXTO para arquivos de Editores de Texto at

Answer (score 0):

O certo não seria gravar o conteúdo do `f_richedit.RichEdit`??

```
  fdm.RichStream := TStringStream.Create(fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.AsAnsiString);
  //fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.SaveToStream(fdm.RichStream);

  f_richedit := Tf_richedit.Create(nil);
  fdm.RichStream.Position := 0;
  f_richedit.RichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(fdm.RichStream);
  TFuncoes.pJustRichEdit(f_richedit.RichEdit, False);
  f_richedit.ShowModal;

  if (fdm.Salvar) then
  begin
    fdm.zqrAux_Aet_Texto.Edit;
    fdm.RichStream.Position := 0;
    fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.AsString := f_richedit.RichEdit.Lines.Text;
    fdm.zqrAux_Aet_Texto.Post;
    fdm.zConecta.Commit;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(fdm.RichStream); // .Free;
  fdm.zqrAux_Aet_Texto.Close;
  f_richedit := nil;
```

**Editado**

Não sei se você já tentou mas tente fazer assim, você salva no Stream, formata o texto no richedit e depois salva novamente no stream antes de salvar no BD.
Quando for exibir o texto onde você quer, use o LoadFromFile.

Obs.: Deixe a propriedade PlainText do richedit como False.

```
  //fdm.RichStream := TStringStream.Create(fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.AsAnsiString);
  fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.SaveToStream(fdm.RichStream);

  f_richedit := Tf_richedit.Create(nil);
  fdm.RichStream.Position := 0;
  f_richedit.RichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(fdm.RichStream);
  TFuncoes.pJustRichEdit(f_richedit.RichEdit, False);
  f_richedit.ShowModal;

  {Colocar aqui a função para limpar o fdm.RichStream aqui antes de salvar novamente, não lembro como é}
  f_richedit.RichEdit.Lines.SaveToStream(fdm.RichStream);

  if(fdm.Salvar)then
  begin
    fdm.zqrAux_Aet_Texto.Edit;
    fdm.RichStream.Position := 0;
    fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.LoadFromStream(fdm.RichStream);//AsString := fdm.RichStream.DataString;
    fdm.zqrAux_Aet_Texto.Post;
    fdm.zConecta.Commit;
  end;

  fdm.zqrAux_Aet_Texto.Close;
  FreeAndNil(fdm.RichStream); // .Free;
  FreeAndNil(f_richedit);
```

Comment: Se você gravar o Line.Text ele grava o texto sem formatação

Comment: Tente então apenas `f_richedit.RichEdit.Text` e marque a opção do richedit PlainText como False

Comment: Pois é, ja tentei... ele traz o texto puro... tambem pensei nessa possibilidade

Comment: Mais uma vez, tente `f_richedit.RichEdit.SavetoStream(oSuaStream)` e depois faça como voc~e já estava fazendo `fdm.zqrAux_Aet_TextoDiversas.LoadFromStream(fdm.RichStream);`

Comment: Então Matheus, eu já fiz isso se olhar na linha comentada, mas o erro continua... sabe quando você fica sem chão... a empresa trabalhando e o erro persistindo... eu trocaria tudo por html, pois dá pra trabalhar melhor com webbrowser, mas ja existem trocentos mil orçamentos feitos assim... vou ter que fazer uma aplicação pra fazer essa correção... e mesmo assim corro o risco de ter problemas na conversão, pois muitos textos vieram do word... e esse bendito word enche o texto de lixo.

Comment: Entendo, alguns erros as vezes por mais "simples" que sejam, fazem a gente perder dias... Verifique a edição da minha resposta.